# Why am I not getting any accelerometer update?

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion

I am trying to get accelerometer updates with CoreMotion and Swift, here is what I placed in my viewDidLoad :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let motionManager = CMMotionManager()
    motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.2
    motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()) {
        (info:CMAccelerometerData!,error:NSError!) in
        if error != nil {
            println(error)
        }
        else {
            println("OK")
        }
    }
}
```

**The problem is that it looks like my closure never gets called (I don't have anything in the console), do you know why?**

Comment: Yes I do know why. Thank you for playing. :)

Comment: @matt Oh, I would have been happy to play, but it was night where I live :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the variable `motionManager`, to which your CMMotionManager instance is assigned, is declared as a local variable (in the body of the function `viewDidLoad`), which means that it goes out of existence when the function finishes executing. Therefore its lifetime is about a 10000th of a second.

Well, that is not long enough for your CMMotionManager to obtain very many updates!

Comment: If you don't understand variable lifetimes, you might want to read this section of the Swift tutorial I've just written: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_variable_scope_and_lifetime