# I'm trying to do some animation in iOS swift and Not able to get the gravity working , here is my code the red box just stays with out moving

Tags: swift, uidynamicanimator, uigravitybehavior

The gravity doesn't seem to do anything , just can't figure out how to get it to work. here is my code the red box just stays with out moving .any help would be appreciated
    import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var box : UIView = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            addBox(CGRectMake(100, 100, 30, 30))
        createAnimation()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    func addBox(location: CGRect) {
        let newBox = UIView(frame: location)
        newBox.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        view.insertSubview(newBox, atIndex: 0)
        box = newBox

    }

    func createAnimation(){
        var animate = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: self.view)
        println("animation")
        var gravity = UIGravityBehavior(items: [box])

        gravity.gravityDirection = CGVectorMake(0, 0.6)
        animate.addBehavior(gravity)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `animate`, your UIDynamicAnimator, is declared as a local variable. Thus it comes into existence and goes right back out of existence again, with no time to animate anything. Declare it as an instance variable instead.

Comment: Actually identical to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27930175/why-am-i-not-getting-any-accelerometer-update - see my answer there for more detail.

Comment: For working example code from my book, see here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch04p175dynamics/Dynamics/ViewController.swift Note how `anim` (my animator) is declared and how it is initialized.

Comment: Not seems. _Is_ the problem. If you do not understand what a variable is and what variable lifetime is about (and it doesn't seem that you do), you might want to look at this Swift tutorial I've just written: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_variable_scope_and_lifetime

Comment: thanks, and one more question. The above code was a test code , so I implemented the same logic on views like this

Comment: Thats the dropbox link to the document and in the method   func setUpAnimationsForSlideView()  the gravity works but the collision doesn't work so the view won't stop from sliding out

Comment: "Thanks and one more question". No: thanks and _not_ one more question. You asked a question, I answered it. End of exchange. If you have another question, click the Ask Question button and ask a new question. Please do not use comments to leech off the existing question. _This_ question is answered - and I believe I answered it clearly and correctly.